# When dependent clauses require commas, when do they allow them, and when are they definitely incorrect?

Tags: punctuation, syntax, clauses, commas

I've been writing in English for many years, but there are certain recurring issues that come up in my writing, which I can't seem to resolve permanently. Primarily I have a problem with punctuation. In my native language, commas are very commonly used. One would place a comma to separate any portion of the sentence that serves a specific grammatical role. At least, this is the case according to the rules I was taught in school.

I can see when I write in English that there are extraneous commas, but I can't always figure out which ones, and why. When dependent clauses require commas, when do they allow them, and when are they definitely incorrect?

Comment: As a side note, in your question, I would remove the comma between _writing_ and _which_: _I've been writing in English for many years, but there are certain recurring issues that come up in my writing which I can't seem to resolve permanently._

Answer (score 8):

Learners from German or Russian (for example) will tend to place too many commas. When writing in English, try to think of commas as a very "heavy" form of punctuation, i.e. that it signifies a substantial pause – it's not just something you fly over as in German or Russian.

Whether to place a comma or not is sometimes a personal choice. For instance, introductory clauses may have a comma but it can be dropped (if the clause is reasonably short):

- Before leaving, I checked my e-mails vs. Before leaving I checked my e-mails.

However, there are some situations where you *must* set a comma:

- **A relative clause** (which, who) **that does not help identify an object** is separated by a comma from the main clause. Compare "The house which I bought" (Oh, you mean *that* house) vs. "The table, which my grandfather already had" (it is clear I mean *this* table right here and I'm providing additional information).
- **Adverbs at the start of a sentence** (Additionally, it must be noted... Unfortunately, I can't...).
- **Adverbs describing the whole sentence at the end.** He died in the car crash, sadly.
- The year is separated from the day and month in **dates.** 2014-07-03 is written as *the 3rd of July, 2014*.
- **Direct speech.** She said, "Where did you go?" "I'm right here," he said. (Notice the comma is inside the double quotes, though I do believe that's predominantly in use in the US.)
- Use a comma **after "yes" or "no."** Yes, I understand. No, it's too late.
- **Conditional sentences.** A comma is put between the "if" clause at the beginning and the second part, but not the other way around: If I arrive early, I'll call you to pick me up vs. I'll call you to pick me up if I arrive early.
- **Lists.** Items of a list are separated by commas, except for the last one: *There were books, bottles and pens in his bag.* A comma can also be seen before the *and* sometimes, though that feels rather wrong to me, especially for lists with short items, such as this example.
- **Adjectives and adverbs.** A collection of independent adjectives or adverbs should also be separated by commas: *the old, scary house*. No comma should be placed if the first adjective refers to the second one: *the new red car*, i.e. *new* refers to *the red car*, not just *car*.
- **Addressing someone.** *Hi, Paul! Thanks for the book, Mary!*

Do **not** place a comma before "that" in things like "**I think that** she's sick." That's the first thing you want to avoid if your native language makes you do that.

Another thing to avoid in most cases is a comma before "because" and similar:

- I'm here because I was invited. My friend will be sleeping here for a few days **because** his family is going through something.

Comment: Hi ljacqu, +1 except the rule about comma after salutation is more a *should* than a *must* these days, especially with email (and comments).  Also, you may want to include between multiple adverbs, adjectives, list items etc.

Comment: @mcalex Thanks a lot for the feedback – I hope my edit has done your comment justice. Take care!
(Keeping the thing about addressing people, though I've moved it to the end of the list :P)

Comment: Well summarised. One very small comment: I don't use a comma between the month and year of a date - in fact I don't use 'rd of', either: 3 July 2014. This was house style at a publishing company I worked for, and became firmly fixed in my mind. (But if the format was July 3, 2014 I would use the comma.)